# Image Sequences -> performance hit?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My question is basically using `UIImageViews` and their `animationImages`.
Since I need a pause, I am now using quite a bit of the same "empty frames" of my animation just so that I achieve a simple pause.
My question is basically, if I use a lot of the same image, Does it actually using more GPU/CPU memory or is it affecting only the length of the stored array of images which is negligible?

Is the image sequence real time generated or is it pre-rendered (I guess this is the essence of this question)